# R: sfnetworks: How to find routes between multiple A and B locations in a same dataset

Tags: r, shortest-path, stplanr, sfnetwork

This is my dataset

```
df<-tribble(
  ~"shop.x",~"shop.y", ~"cust.x", ~"cust.y",
  78.100378,    9.944226,   78.096318,  9.954789,
  78.101155,    9.932190,   78.089824,  9.929975,
  78.141887,    9.928319,   78.110863,  9.952235,
  78.100381,    9.944226,   78.104066,  9.97013,
  78.097206,    9.948872,   78.11631,   9.947862
)
```

The df dataset has locations of shops and the customers.

I want to create shortest path route for each row (for every shop to customer location) using OSM map in R. Is it possible using sfnetworks?

The local road networks data is [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/151ghDbxjT9poPL4GiYhDfYuBRLAKimqk?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you show what you already tried?

Comment: routes <- list()
points1<-df
  for (j in 1:(nrow(points1)-1)) {
  path <- st_network_paths(
    network, 
    from = st_geometry(points1)[j], 
    to = st_geometry(points1)[j + 1]
  )
  
  routes[[j]] <- path 
  }

Comment: i just knew the above code which takes origin as row 1 and destination as row 2. Im unaware of how to dfo the same operation between columns instead of rows

Comment: Can you please check the coordinates of the input data? The first and the second shops have identical coords; the third and the fourth shops have identical coords.

Comment: I dont have any problem with the location of shops. But, anyways I had changed it now. I dont want all these routes to be combined into one continuous route. Rather I want each row's with separate routes.

Comment: Hi @Betel, it might be useful to post your network and some more things you have tried. I would start by saying that you could convert your dataframe into sf objects (one for the shops and another for the cust(omers?)), which can then be given to the to and from arguments within an `apply` function using `st_network_paths()`, without some more input it is hard to find exactly where you need help.

Comment: Thanks @loreabad6. Here is the link for it :https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/151ghDbxjT9poPL4GiYhDfYuBRLAKimqk?usp=sharing

Comment: sounds like a homework question! You should include the code you've tried so far

Comment: Hi @Betel, thank you for adding the data. I still think you could post more of what you tested, and also what you want the output to look like. I added an answer below, but since I am not sure what you are looking for as a route (a LINESTRING, set of coordinates, indices within the network), I am unsure how to structure the final result. Most of the code from my answer is from the [sfnetworks documentation](https://luukvdmeer.github.io/sfnetworks/articles/) which could be useful for you1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, since this dataframe contains mainly coordinates in X and Y for shops and customers, I convert them into `sf` objects. Two objects for each set.

```r
# Load packages
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(sfnetworks)
library(tidygraph)

# Load the data
df <- tribble(
  ~"shop.x",~"shop.y", ~"cust.x", ~"cust.y",
  78.100378,    9.944226,   78.096318,  9.954789,
  78.101155,    9.932190,   78.089824,  9.929975,
  78.141887,    9.928319,   78.110863,  9.952235,
  78.100381,    9.944226,   78.104066,  9.97013,
  78.097206,    9.948872,   78.11631,   9.947862
)

# Convert into sf objects
shop = st_as_sf(df[,1:2], crs = 4326, coords = c("shop.x", "shop.y"))
cust = st_as_sf(df[,3:4], crs = 4326, coords = c("cust.x", "cust.y"))
```

The roads are `LINESTRINGS` which can be converted into a `sfnetwork` object. The network needs to be cleaned. More info on how to do network pre-processing [here](https://luukvdmeer.github.io/sfnetworks/articles/preprocess_and_clean.html).

```r
## I downloaded the data attached and saved it locally 
roads_dir = "data/roads.shp"
roads = st_read(roads_dir, crs = 4326)
#> Reading layer `Roads' from data source 
#> Simple feature collection with 6915 features and 0 fields
#> Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 78.0217 ymin: 9.832762 xmax: 78.22482 ymax: 10.04193
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84

# Convert into an sfnetwork
roads_sfn = as_sfnetwork(roads, directed = FALSE)

# Do some network cleaning
roads_clean = roads_sfn %>% 
  convert(to_spatial_subdivision, .clean = TRUE) %>% 
  convert(to_spatial_smooth, .clean = TRUE)
```

To calculate the paths we can use an mapply function to the `st_network_paths()` function passing the from argument with the locations of the shops, and the to argument with the locations of the customers. Hence, the paths are calculated in order for each combination.

```r
# Calculate the specified paths.
paths = mapply(
  st_network_paths,
  from = shop,
  to = cust,
  MoreArgs = list(x = roads_clean)
)["node_paths", ] %>%
  unlist(recursive = FALSE)
#> although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_nearest_points assumes that they are planar
#> although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_nearest_points assumes that they are planar
#> Warning: Although argument from has length > 1, only the first element is used
```

The output is a list with five elements containing the node indices for each route, which correspond to the nodes in the original network.

```r
paths[[1]]
#>  [1]  1842  1843 12191 12190   232  7977  7843 12174  8244  8205  7914  8139
#> [13]  8209  7958  7957  8229  8230  8328
```

If we want to get the path as a network itself, we can slice the original network as:

```r
roads_clean %>%
  activate("nodes") %>%
  slice(paths[[1]])
#> # A sfnetwork with 18 nodes and 17 edges
#> #
#> # CRS:  EPSG:4326 
#> #
#> # An unrooted tree with spatially explicit edges
#> #
#> # Node Data:     18 x 1 (active)
#> # Geometry type: POINT
#> # Dimension:     XY
#> # Bounding box:  xmin: 78.09568 ymin: 9.943727 xmax: 78.10051 ymax: 9.955158
#>              geometry
#>           <POINT [°]>
#> 1 (78.10001 9.946228)
#> 2 (78.10051 9.943727)
#> 3 (78.10017 9.945039)
#> 4 (78.09918 9.951894)
#> 5 (78.09895 9.953372)
#> 6 (78.09647 9.955099)
#> # ... with 12 more rows
#> #
#> # Edge Data:     17 x 3
#> # Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> # Dimension:     XY
#> # Bounding box:  xmin: 78.09568 ymin: 9.943727 xmax: 78.10051 ymax: 9.955158
#>    from    to                                                  geometry
#>   <int> <int>                                          <LINESTRING [°]>
#> 1     2     3 (78.10051 9.943727, 78.10029 9.944423, 78.10017 9.945039)
#> 2     6     7                    (78.09647 9.955099, 78.09877 9.954435)
#> 3    12    13                    (78.09569 9.955158, 78.09568 9.954763)
#> # ... with 14 more rows
```